# Sorting in hierarchy data in javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, sorting

I have populate the hierarchy data in the following structure.

**Screen shot:**

[image]

In this i want to perform the sorting.  In this case i have the flat data object for rendereing. For Expample. I have rendering object as like

renderedobjects=[ {1,...},{2,....} ...];

And also i have tried with sorting by looping the renderedobject and each object have Level property . but it take more time to perform rearrange the rendered objects . Is there any other way to perform this sorting.

**Update Screen shots:**
**Screen shot 1:**
[image]

**Screen shot 2:**
[image]

**Screen shot 3:**
[image]

**Update:**
Hi if it is possible please share the algorithm for perform hierarchial data sorting based on the indent level using recursive functions

Comment: Can you provide more detailed example of rendered object? How one level nested to another?

Comment: @kharandziuk i have attached the screen shot for renderedobject format .Please do the need full for this. Thanks in advance

Comment: What property of the object should be used to sort?

Comment: I have tried with sort TaskName (int type)

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented TreeGrid by using a YUI example given below. Its pretty easy and has nice JSON pattern for data object.

http://jafl.github.io/yui2/treeble/

Hope this helps.